# KeyError in BeautifulSoup page crawling

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm writing a small app that involves crawling certain fixed websites. In this case I'm crawling TechCrunch, and am stuck because I'm getting a `KeyError` where I really shouldn't be.

Here's the part of code that does the crawling:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), "html.parser")

chunks = soup.find_all('li', class_='river-block')
html = 'TechCrunch:'
html += '<ul>'
for c in chunks:
    print(c.attrs.keys())
    print(c.attrs.values())
    html += '<li>'
    html += c.attrs['data-sharetitle']
    html += '<a href="' + c.attrs['data-permalink'] + '">Read more</a>'
    html += '</li>'
    html += '</ul>'
```

The idea is that the link and the headline are stored in `data-permalink` and `data-sharetitle` attributes, respectively. Now, the output of the two print statements is what I'd expect:

```
dict_keys(['class', 'data-sharetitle', 'id', 'data-shortlink', 'data-permalink'])
dict_values([['river-block', 'crunch-network'], 'Investing In Artificial\xa0Intelligence', '1251865', 'http://tcrn.ch/1mEbmcG', 'http://techcrunch.com/2015/12/25/investing-in-artificial-intelligence/'])
```

However, the line `html += c.attrs['data-sharetitle']` gives me `KeyError: 'data-sharetitle'`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every `li` element with `river-block` class has `data-sharetitle` attribute. *Enforce the presence of the desired attributes*. Replace:

```
chunks = soup.find_all('li', class_='river-block')
```

with:

```
chunks = soup.find_all('li', {"class": "river-block", 
                              "data-sharetitle": True, 
                              "data-permalink": True})
```

Comment: Thanks! While at a cursory look it looked like every `li` had the class `river-block`, I now notice that there are other `li` within the `li` I'm after.